# Custom colors in JustGage not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, raphael, justgage

I am trying to add custom sectors to my JustGage object and when I add them it is just showing the default of:

0-25 = green, 25-50 = yellow, 50-100 = red

I want to have it split like this:

0-25 = red, 25-50 = orange, 50-75 = yellow, 75-100 = green

My code is below. I have defined my customSectors as I want them, but the gage still defaults back to the original 3 sectors. Am I doing something wrong here. I tried to find some documentation on JustGage, but there really isn't any.

```
var Gage1 = new JustGage({
id: "gage-1", 
value: 100, 
min: 0,
max: 100,
showInnerShadow: false,
shadowOpacity : 0.3,
customSectors: [{
    color : "#CE1B21",
    lo : 0,
    hi : 25
}, {
    color : "#D0532A",
    lo : 25,
    hi : 50
}, {
    color : "#FFC414",
    lo : 50,
    hi : 75
}, {
    color : "#85A137",
    lo : 75,
    hi : 100
}],
valueFontColor : ['#4A98BE'], 
gaugeColor : ['#333'], 
    title: "Demo Gage",
label: "%"
});
```

NOTE: I am using justgage.1.0.1.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is levelColors:

```
var Gage1 = new JustGage({
  id: "gage-1", 
  value: 100, 
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  levelColors: ['#CE1B21', '#D0532A', '#FFC414', '#85A137']
});
```

I don't think justGage supports you choosing exactly the min and max for each color you want. And you may need to mess around with the option `levelColorsGradient` try setting it to `false` first.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks. Do you know if there is a place that has good documentation on this plugin?

Comment: All I know about is http://justgage.com/ and you can click on customize style at the bottom.

Comment: No problem, so did you need to use levelColorsGradient?

Comment: No I did not. I just used the levelColors and it was good. Seems like the default value for levelColorsGradient is what it needs to be set at anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the latest version of justgage, you will see that 'customSectors' is in the code where if you download from their site, 'customSectors' doesn't exist.

Use the below link to get the latest and your code should work just fine.

https://raw.github.com/toorshia/justgage/master/justgage.js

Answer (score 0):

Config that worked for me:

```
  config = {
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 600000,
    decimals: 0,
    gaugeWidthScale: 0.6,
    label: '$',
    formatNumber: true,
    customSectors: {
      percents: true,
      ranges: [
        {lo: 0, hi: 33, color: '#13ED5A'}, // lo and hi values are in %
        {lo: 34, hi: 67, color: '#49D61C'},
        {lo: 68, hi: 100, color: '#49AB1C'}
      ]
    }
  };
```